# Can't click login into admin account

Tags: greeter

Hi My elementary OS was working just fine, I don't know what the kids have done, it am not able to login to my account..

I have one personal account and one other is guest account.. Im trying to log into personal account but the click is not working, but when i click on guest account, the click is working and guest account says this

[image]

and when i click Ok, it disappear and after that i cannot do anything, can't even restart or shutdown, its just empty everywhere..

but main question, why i am not able to click on personal account when im trying to login into personal account. why it does't click on it, nothing happens but works for guest account.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+Alt+F1 will lead u to terminal. Login to terminal with regular user and do: "rm -rf ~/.config" and reboot your PC. Keep in mind that u will lose your app settings.

Comment: I have some important data for my final year project for my university, it was saved on documents and download folder, will this get deleted?? i will get screwed if it gets deleted.. I don't want to lose my data..

Comment: No, this will only delete some configuration files in an attempt to restore the ability to login.